# Interpolation method

Tags: reference-request, interpolation

I am researching about different interpolation methods, and their pros and cons. Please help me to understand ideas behind Gaussian interpolation method. Although, I looked at different papers for this, I could not get even the basic concept. If you can give me links to resources, that would be great help too. Thanks.

Comment: Is gaussian interpolation method just radial basis function interpolation with gaussian kernel?

Comment: I don't know. If you have more ideas, I would be thankful for sharing them to me.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you tell us what kind of data do you want to interpolate.

Comment: I don't have a data set. Just trying to learn about Gaussian interpolation in general.

Comment: Can you provide some reference to the Gaussian interpolation? Probably the texts you are studying. Because I don't know what Gaussian interpolation is.

Comment: see, you are asking me my question.

Comment: upaudel, the problem is that Gauss has his name on so many various techniques that it is difficult to understand which one you are asking about.  Can you tell us what you hope to apply this interpolation to?  Is it images, time series data, or something else?  What field is the work (electrical engineering, image processing, statistics, biology, etc?) Can you provide the name of a paper or two you have consulted?

Comment: do you mean **lagrange** interpolation?